# Why would you flour your bread loaf pans?

Tags: bread

I found a recipe for white bread that says to grease the pan and then flour it. I know you do that with some cakes, but I have never seen a bread recipe that calls for flour in the pans. I thought I was reading it wrong, I had my husband read it he said I was not seeing thing. sIt really called for flour in the pans. Are there any benefits to doing this?

Answer (score 4):

The same benefit as there is for cakes-- namely that it should prevent sticking. Usually is less necessary for bread since there's usually less sugar in bread and that makes it less likely to stick. Greasing and flouring does produce a thicker crust where the pan is.